# How to show a .cshtml within a div of another file via typescript

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc

I am new with ASP.NET MVC and am stuck trying to figure this out. I have page that has a few tabs and would like the content inside each Tab div to render all content of another .cshtml file (ideally with a model).

```
<div id="Tabs">
    <ul id ="TabMenu">
        <li><a href="#Main"><span>Main</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Notes"><span>Notes</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="TabMain" class="tab-pane">
        @*code for content of Main tab*@
    </div>
    <div id="Notes" class="tab-pane">
        @*code for content of Notes tab*@
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this is my .ts file but it doesn't seem to work.
document.create

```
AddCshtmlToTab(itemId: string) {
    var tab = document.getElementById("TabMain");
    var partialView = document.createTextNode(`@Html.Partial("~/Views/tabMain.cshtml")`); /*?model??*/
    tab.appendChild(partialView);
}
```